# A simple two way encryption techniques/Algorithm using a key?

Tags: visual-c++, encryption, bluetooth

I am a novice in this topic so I am going to describe my problem. I have a file which contains a long term key (for bonding via bluetooth) and data from the bluetooth device to my host PC. I want to encrypt this bits of this file using a two way encryption using a key. The encryption can be simple.

My Approach

I have used rijndael AED encrytion technique which can be. Thanks all for your time.

Comment: The simplest encryption possible is "do not encrypt". It is very easy to implement too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an XOR encryption.
Its suitable for simple encryption.

Here the key is used for encryption. You can change it as you want.

For decryption just do it twice.

`Google`=> `XOR` => `-,#)#` => `XOR` => `Google`

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
 char string[7]= "Google"; 
 char key[7]="ABCDEF";
 for(int x=0; x<6; x++)
 {
  string[x]=string[x]^key[x];
  std::cout<<string[x];
 }
}
```